# Zabbix 5 Tomcat Jmx not supported items

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, zabbix, tomcat9

Im trying to use Template App Apache Tomcat JMX template for monitoring Tomcat 9
im added neccesary parameters in tomcat JAVA_OPTS=

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8085 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.17.233.198 \
```

And some items working properly  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Jb3.png)
but some items not supported
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdqBc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHWFX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Z2z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwYwG.png)
How can ı fix this not supported jmx items ?
or what is wrong my configuration
if you need any detail abuth server.xml etc. pls ask
thx for help
EDİT:
ım install jconsole from  opensdk11 and my server is running on openjdk 11.0.11  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRKmF.png)
after that screen click connect jconsole show me empty screen like that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxXXC.png) and ı cant find any log file for debug that
also that command dosnt work for my case
jdk-11\bin>jconsole.exe -Jjava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -debug

Comment: The names of the exported beans depend on Tomcat's configuration, so some elements contained in the template (like the HTTPS connector) simply don't exist in your Tomcat. Use `jconsole` to explore the available beans.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that template has quite a few of hard coded items. I made a variation on this template which is using a lot more low level discoveries. You might want to see if this is a nice starting point for you.
[my-zabbix-templates/Java/](https://github.com/ikzelf/my-zabbix-templates/tree/main/Java)

On this level you will always need some customisation. Feel free to try and come up with useful suggestions.